# video effect while recording fails on universal platform app

Tags: c++, uwp

Using the mediacapture class on a universal platform app, I am attempting to add an overlay effect on a recording.  The overlay effect works fine on the preview, and on recording if I set the effect prior to starting the record.  If I try to set the effect during a recording, the system generates an exception: "The data specified for the media type is invalid, inconsistent, or not supported by this object".  What would cause it to fail only during an active record session?

```
            VideoEffectDefinition^ effect = ref new VideoEffectDefinition("CompositionEffectLibrary.CompositionEffect", props);
        if (mediaCapture->MediaCaptureSettings->VideoDeviceCharacteristic == VideoDeviceCharacteristic::AllStreamsIdentical ||
            mediaCapture->MediaCaptureSettings->VideoDeviceCharacteristic == VideoDeviceCharacteristic::PreviewRecordStreamsIdentical)
        {
            // This effect will modify both the preview and the record streams, because they are the same stream.
            create_task(mediaCapture->AddVideoEffectAsync(effect, MediaStreamType::VideoRecord))
                .then([this](IMediaExtension^ mediaExtension)
            {
            });
        }

        else
        {
            create_task(mediaCapture->AddVideoEffectAsync(effect, MediaStreamType::VideoRecord))
                .then([this, effect](IMediaExtension^ mediaExtension)
            {
                auto mediaCapture = m_mediaCaptureMgr.Get();
                create_task(mediaCapture->AddVideoEffectAsync(effect, MediaStreamType::VideoPreview))
                    .then([this](IMediaExtension^ mediaExtension)
                {
                });
            });
        } // else

    return true;
```

I ran the program with the canned VideoStabilization effect, and had no problems, so it seems to be related to using a custom class.  I am including it also.  There were no compile errors or warnings and uses the Win2D package.

C++ Effect Class

```
public ref class CompositionEffect sealed : public IBasicVideoEffect
{
    CanvasDevice^ _canvasDevice = nullptr;
    CanvasBitmap^ _overlayBitmap = nullptr;
    IRandomAccessStream^ _overlayStream;
    int _offsetX;
    int _offsetY;
    int _width;
    int _height;
    bool _atTop;
    int _position;
    float _opacity;
    bool _layerCreated = false;
    CanvasActiveLayer^ _activeLayer = nullptr;
    Vector<VideoEncodingProperties^>^ _videoEncProps;

public:
    CompositionEffect()
    {
        VideoEncodingProperties^ encodingProperties = ref new VideoEncodingProperties();
        encodingProperties->Subtype = "ARGB32";
        _videoEncProps = ref new Vector<VideoEncodingProperties^>{ encodingProperties };
    }

    property bool IsReadOnly
    {
        virtual bool get() { return true; }
    }

    property IVectorView<VideoEncodingProperties^> ^SupportedEncodingProperties
    {
        virtual IVectorView<VideoEncodingProperties^> ^get() { return _videoEncProps->GetView(); }
    }

    property MediaMemoryTypes SupportedMemoryTypes
    {
        virtual MediaMemoryTypes get() { return MediaMemoryTypes::Gpu; }
    }

    property bool TimeIndependent
    {
        virtual bool get() { return true; }
    }

    // Get positional information from loaded image
    virtual void CompositionEffect::SetEncodingProperties(VideoEncodingProperties^ encodingProperties, IDirect3DDevice^ device)
    {
        if (_canvasDevice != nullptr)
            return;

        _canvasDevice = CanvasDevice::CreateFromDirect3D11Device(device);

        create_task(CanvasBitmap::LoadAsync(_canvasDevice, _overlayStream)).then([this](CanvasBitmap^ bmp)
        {
            _overlayBitmap = bmp;

            // overlay at left side of source
            if (_position == 0)
            {
                _offsetX = 0;
            }

            // overlay at right side of source
            else if (_position == 2)
            {
                _offsetX = _width - bmp->SizeInPixels.Width;
            }

            // overlay at center of source
            else
            {
                _offsetX = (_width - bmp->SizeInPixels.Width) / 2;
            }

            // Set overlay vertical position
            if (_atTop)
            {
                _offsetY = 0;
            }

            else
            {
                _offsetY = (_height - bmp->SizeInPixels.Height);
            }
        });
    }

    virtual void Close(MediaEffectClosedReason reason)
    {
    }

    virtual void DiscardQueuedFrames() { }

    // Draw overlay image over source image at specified coordinates
    virtual void ProcessFrame(ProcessVideoFrameContext^ context)
    {           

        IDirect3DSurface^ outputSurface = context->OutputFrame->Direct3DSurface;
        CanvasRenderTarget^ renderTarget = CanvasRenderTarget::CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(_canvasDevice, outputSurface);
        CanvasDrawingSession^ drawSession = renderTarget->CreateDrawingSession();
        _activeLayer = drawSession->CreateLayer(_opacity);

        if (_overlayBitmap != nullptr)
        {
            drawSession->DrawImage(_overlayBitmap, (float)_offsetX, (float)_offsetY);
        }

        delete(_activeLayer);
    }

    // Set the operational parameters of the effect
    virtual void SetProperties(IPropertySet^ configuration) 
    {
        _overlayStream = (IRandomAccessStream^)configuration->Lookup("bitmap");
        _width = (int)configuration->Lookup("width");
        _height = (int)configuration->Lookup("height");
        _opacity = (float)(int)configuration->Lookup("opacity");
        _opacity /= 100;
        _atTop = (bool)configuration->Lookup("attop");
        _position = (int)configuration->Lookup("position");
    }

};
```

I wrote a simple example in C# and tried it on my development machine, and it failed the same way with the "data specified for the media type ..." message.  I then placed the program on another machine, and it worked fine????  I have the effect set up for Cpu instead of Gpu, so it makes no sense for it to behave differently across platforms running the same 4.6 framework.  Here is a link to the test program [TestVideoApp2](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuPA5TUtivDpgmDxXJm7FE5XztxE)

I have discovered some additional info regarding this issue.  It appears that the input stream was set to YUY2.  I changed this to NV12, and it started working.  Unfortunately, I changed cameras and even though the new camera supported this output format, it failed with the invalid media type.  It seems to be related to the input media type vs the supported media type of the effect.  Not sure what the relationship is here but some progress is being made.  Perhaps someone knows what the video input vs effect media types are supposed to be to work properly.

OK, it appears I have to change the input format from the camera (YUY2 or NV12) to ARGB32 in process frame, and probably back to NV12 when I exit, and also set YUY2 or NV12 as supported types. What is failing is that the supported effect media type is ARGB32 and is hitting the NV12 media stream input filter type of the recording.  Does this sound reasonable??  Is there a more straight forward approach as this could get quite painful.

I found a solution to the problem by setting the input format of the effect to YUY2 and then converting it over to BGR8 via SoftwareBitmap.Convert.  From there I did the effect manually via pixel byte arrays and then converted back to YUY2 before returning from ProcessFrame.  This seems to work fine now.  Unfortunately, I cannot use Win2D since it does not support YUY2.  I would like a GPU solution, but for now the CPU solution seems to solve my immediate needs.  Perhaps someone else may be able to come up with a solution using the GPU.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Adding video effect during recording works in my side. Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?